# Run a php script in the background

Tags: php, background, exe

I am trying to run a php script in the background on windows.
Basically my goal is to run a exe file in the background and receive a signal when its done.
I'm open to any suggestions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

make a ***.bat*** file and on that bat file reference php file then it will work

Answer (score 0):

if your using linux environment, i suggest creating a bash file and put your commands.

and if your using windows environment, use .bat file and put your commands.

```
php filename.php <arguments>
php another_filename.php <arguments>
```

and then run in in the terminal.. for the signal, you can `exit()` your php script based on what the condition your script needs..

**UPDATE**

Regarding your comment, if you want the webpage to create an executable then you must use the backtick or `exec()` in your web php file

for example, in your web php file:

```
//other php codes
echo `php runthisfile.php`;
echo exec('php runthisfile.php');
//other php codes
```

then if this is encountered, in the background, it will run the runthisfile.php file.. the backtick is a special symbol in php and `exec()` is a function that enables you to execute command line instructions..

and regarding the signalling, there are many approach.. some are:

1. in the background file, you can store a value in the database that the web page is listening to
2. make a [soap call](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) that uses xml as its data medium
3. or if what I think is right, just use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) in your web.. it really is helpful

Comment: Maybe i explained it wrong ...i have a web page and a php script i want the web page to call the script and continue runing , when the script is done i want to know about it in the webpage . Thanks

Comment: Hi, @YuriTupizin I updated my answer and I hope that you'll learn a thing or two from my answer..